# Prerequisites for deploying a .NET C++/CLI DLL?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, c++-cli

I've written a C++/CLI DLL to be used with my GUI .NET application. On my local development machine, everything works as expected. My GUI application says that it cannot load my C++/CLI DLL on any other machine, though. It always says that it cannot load my DLL or one of its' dependencies. So I was thinking maybe it's some missing C runtime or something?

Are there any prerequisites that need to be installed prior to using my C++/CLI DLL on another machine? Strictly from a .NET perspective, or C++ run-time, or whatever.

Edit: Sorry. It's VS2012, .NET 4.0, Platform Toolset v110.

Comment: "cannot load" = BadImageFormatException? Then it's a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue. Are you using .NET 4.5?

Comment: You'll need to document the VS version and runtime error better.  But yes, C++/CLI assemblies have a prerequisite for the C++ runtime support DLLs.

Comment: .NET version is the one.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. I'm using VS2012, .NET 4.0 and platform toolset v110.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the dependencies that other .Net languages have (e.g., the .Net framework), C++/CLI requires the C++ runtime.

You can [download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) the C++ runtime redistributable for VS 2012 from Microsoft. Select the x86 or x64 version based on the compilation setting of your C++/CLI assembly, not the version of Windows the target machine is running.

Note that this is the runtime for Release compiles only. Debug compiles use a different runtime, which does not have a redistributable, and is only installed with Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. I was deploying my C++/CLI Debug-compiled DLL. I had to switch it to the Release configuration and it works now.